# why does this javascript function not work when called from a webview?

Tags: javascript, android-webview

When the following function is called from a browser, the expected file is correctly downloaded.

When I display the same page in a `WebView` and I click on the same button, no file is downloaded.

```
async function downloadFile(url, filename) {
  try {
    // Fetch the file
    const response = await fetch(url);
    
    // Check if the request was successful
    if (response.status != 200) {
      throw new Error(`Unable to download file. HTTP status: ${response.status}`);
    }

    // Get the Blob data
    const blob = await response.blob();

    // Create a download link
    const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
    downloadLink.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    downloadLink.download = filename;

    // Trigger the download
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    downloadLink.click();

    // Clean up
    setTimeout(() => {
      URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadLink.href);
      document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
    }, 100);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error downloading the file:', error.message);
  }
}
```

Why is it so and how should I modify the function in order to get it work in a webview?

***EDIT***

I tried two ways:

1. just opening the page in the ´WebView´ and manually clicking on the button that calls the function. No file is downloaded. Why?
2. executing the following code

   ```
    ....
    bindingHome.webViewBeGolf.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    bindingHome.webViewBeGolf.addJavascriptInterface(new BackgroundScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");
    ....

    public class BackgroundScriptInterface {
      @JavascriptInterface
      public void processHTML(String html) {
        ....
      }
    }

    String historyUrl = "(function() {apex.server.process(" +
          "'XXXXXX',{}," +
          "{success: function(pdata){" +
             "if(pdata.mode == -1){" +
               "alert_isb(pdata.comment);" +
             "}else{" +
               "let hurl = 'abcd/pdf/get_abcd' + '?ppersoon=' + apex.item('P'+page()+'_USER').getValue()" +
               " + '&pchecksum=' + pdata.checksum;" +
               "const response = fetch(hurl);" +
               "if (response.status != 200) {" +
                 "alert_isb(`Unable to download file. HTTP status: ${response.status}`);" +
               "}else{" +
                 "alert_isb('response.status == 200');}" +
               "}" +
             "}," +
          "error: function (pdata) {alert_isb('Unhandled error: ' + JSON.stringify(pdata));}," +
          "dataType: \"json\"" +
          "});})();";

    bindingHome.webViewBeGolf.evaluateJavascript(item.historyUrl, null);
   ```

With the statement *"const response = fetch(hurl);"* I get an alert that says *Unable to download file. HTTP status: undefined*

With the statement *"const response = **await** fetch(hurl);"* I get no alert, meaning that the process holds, I guess.

In fact my ultimate goal is not to download the file, but to open it to extract the relevant info directly into my app.

Comment: Could you provide your android code to see how the webview is configured?